# Simple SQL Maximum column query

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two columns A and B. I want to select the value of column A where B has its maximum value.

```
SELECT MAX(B) FROM table_name
```

just gives me the value of B.

I can do another query with the value of B to get A, but is there a shorter way with just one SQL query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select A
from MyTable 
where B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM MyTable)
```

or

```
select t.A
from MyTable t
inner join (
    SELECT MAX(B) as BMAX FROM MyTable
) tm on t.B = t.BMAX
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A
  FROM table_name
 WHERE B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM table_name)
```